# orientation detection - images of govt. issued documents

Tags: computer-vision, image-preprocessing, opencv

Trying to figure out a macro approach to detecting the orientation of documents that works across document types (maybe a pipe dream). We successfully used SIFT to detect orientation in documents where we had a logo/emblem but ran into issues with documents issued at the state level (separate from documents issued at the national/federal level). For instance certificates of registration of vehicles.

There is no standard pattern across different states and definitely no common feature/logo/emblem that we can use to triangulate the orientation of the document. It's just a bunch of evenly spread-out text. We have tried thresholding techniques but it doesn't cut it for our use case ..sample image below ..any pointers would be truly and deeply appreciated

[image: sample selection from our document]

Comment: Did you try making 90-deg rotations and checking for text recognition? Seems like it could work, and might be the only really sound way to do it. Anything else is just a heuristic and would be more error-prone.